# the difference between at and to

Tags: grammar

> A woman showed up in khaki dress **at** a protest.
>
> A woman showed up in khaki dress **to** a protest.

To sounds better than at, but I am wondering if both are okay and grammatical and if they mean the same thing.

Comment: Spelling: khaki, as seen in stapmoshun's answer. Also, 'in khaki dress' does not mean the same as 'in **a** khaki dress'.

Comment: This is an interesting question! For no obvious reason, it seems that if we have ***two*** adverbial clauses in such contexts (***to a protest*** and ***in a khaki dress***), there's signiuficant pressure for them to appear in that order. Is there perhaps some kind of "**Royal order of Adverbs**" involved here?

Answer (score -2):

It is helpful to split the sentence and rearrange it to figure out what sounds better.

> At a protest, a woman showed up in a khaki dress.

It wouldn't sound great if this sentence started with "To".

In your situation, both "to" and "at" sound okay... They *do* mean the same thing in this example. But the sentence, overall, can be clarified and tidied up, like in my quote above. Furthermore, "a woman showed up in khaki dress" is correct, it just depends on whether her whole ensemble is khaki or just her dress. (Khaki shoes? That's a new one.)

Comment: "Khaki shoes? That's a new one." [not where I live](https://www.schuh.co.uk/khaki-shoes/)